# Unable get range from NSString for NSURL absoluteString

Tags: ios, object, nsstring, nsurl, nsdatadetector

I'm developing the chat application, where the text entered has to be detected if its URL. If so, change its color and underline it. Please have a look at below screenshot :

[image: color]

To change the color of the url I've used following code:

```
NSString *urlString = [[detetctedURL absoluteString] stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];

            /* *detetctedURL is detected url from entered text using NSDataDetector
            /* *for messageText http://stackoverflow.com/somefolder/any-[thing]-etc, the detectedURL is http://stackoverflow.com/somefolder/any-%5Bthing%5B-etc */

            NSRange r = [messageText rangeOfString:urlString];
            if (r.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                 //colorFromHex 4285f4
                 [atext addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:66.0/255.0 green:133.0/255.0 blue:244.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] range:r];
                 [atext addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle) range:r];
                 //set attributed text (atext) to UILabel               
            }
```

How can I format detected URLs correctly if the messageText contains the URL with both special character and percent encoding both, or only percent encoding ?

Thanks!

**Update :**

With the help of following code, I was able to get the required range. However, its working almost fine for most of the links, but not all like in case if there is charcters such as ']-('.

```
NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
        NSRange r = [messageText rangeOfString:urlString];
        BOOL foundRange = YES;
        if (r.location == NSNotFound)
        {
            foundRange = NO;
            //for umlauts or special characters
            urlString = [[url absoluteString] stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
            r = [messageText rangeOfString:urlString];
            if (r.location == NSNotFound)
            {
                //for white space in url
                urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
                r = [messageText rangeOfString:urlString];

                if (r.location == NSNotFound)
                {
                    urlString = [url absoluteString];
                    NSString *prefix = url.scheme;
                    if(prefix)
                    {
                        prefix = [prefix stringByAppendingString:@"://"];
                        urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:prefix withString:@""];
                        r = [messageText rangeOfString:urlString];
                        if (r.location == NSNotFound)
                        {
                            urlString = [urlString stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
                            r = [messageText rangeOfString:urlString];
                            if (r.location == NSNotFound)
                            {
                                urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
                                r = [messageText rangeOfString:urlString];
                                if (r.location != NSNotFound){ foundRange = YES; }
                            }else{ foundRange = YES; }
                        }else{ foundRange = YES; }
                    }
                }else{ foundRange = YES; }
            }else{ foundRange = YES; }
        }

        if (foundRange)
        {
            //colorFromHex 4285f4
            [atext addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:66.0/255.0 green:133.0/255.0 blue:244.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] range:r];

            [atext addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle) range:r];

            myLabel.attributedText = atext; 
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem here? You are using stringByRemovingPercentEncoding to actually remove the percent encoded url string ? What do you want to do?

Comment: I want the urls having both special characters and percent to be formatted as blue color with underline. But the problem is when we use NSDatadetector to detect url from string, it returns url by adding percent encoding to it, i.e special characters are escaped. At the time of getting range in order to format url, I'm removing percent encoding from url, passing it for getting range and format. This works only when there is special symbol in actual text.(case 2 in attached screenshot). But when actual text already contain percent encoded data, how can we determine that ?

Comment: The data detector will give you the match range directly. No need for you to search the string yourself.

Comment: @KenThomases You're right, but then I'll not be able to format that detected url as per requirement (The color for detected url will be Blue). Is there a way for specifying attributes like textColor, italic, etc. for url detected by NSDataDetector ?

Comment: @iAkki, why won't you be able to format it? You can use the range the data detector gives you in the exact same way you're trying to use the range you get from `-rangeOfString:`.

Comment: @KenThomases Please look at my update, you'll get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSDataDetector` to find and highlight url.

```
NSDataDetector* detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes: NSTextCheckingTypeLink 
                                                           error: nil];

NSArray* matches = [detector matchesInString: source 
                                     options: 0 
                                       range: NSMakeRange(0, [source length])];
```

You can use this to find phone numbers, address etc.

Answer (score 0):

Set .dataDetectorTypes on your text view instead of trying to change the color yourself. The UITextView will take care of highlighting itself.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using UILabel and can't change it due to some restrictions for now.